# Is return statement optional in a method that has return type not void, but throws an Exception?

Tags: java

Here I have a method that is expected to return a boolean :

```
static boolean display()
{
    }
```

The compilation fails as This method must return a result of type boolean.

However, if the method is modified as below:

```
static boolean display()
{
    try{
        throw new ArithmeticException();
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e)
    {
        throw e;

    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println(finally);
    }
}
```

Why does not the compilation fail anymore even though I have not added any return statement.

If in the catch block I do not include a throw statement, the compilation fails again with the previous reason.

Comment: If the method will always throw an exception that is also valid it seems. And it’s understandable since there won’t be any use for a return value then

Comment: I even tink that putting in a `return` statement would cause an “unreachable code” error.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, in the catch block, a return statement after throw or a throw statement after return, both lead to Unreachable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java compiler does a (limited) flow analysis and when it can determine that all flows of control lead to an exception you don't need a return.

Comment: In other words: the compiler insists that it can certify that each flow leads to *either* a `return` or a `throw`. I find it quite logical since each of these statements exits the method.

Answer (score 1):

To understand try putting `return true;` at the end of the method. Then you should get a error calling unreachable statement.

This happens because your method always throwing an exception. So at the end you don't need to return a value, because it already throwing the exception before that and ends the method

Answer (score 0):

You: Why does not the compilation fail anymore even though I have not added any return statement?

> Answer: When you explicitly throw an exception in try block, and again
>   in the catch block you explicitly throw an exception, the compiler
>   does not give an error because you are throwing an exception
>   explicitly using the throw keyword, which terminates abruptly the
>   normal flow of code and stops the execution of all the subsequent code
>   in display method and control gets directly transfer to the calling
>   method

```
    public class StackOverFlowReturn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(display());
        } catch (Exception ae) {
            System.out.println("Arithmetic Exception");
        }
    }

    static boolean display() {
        try {
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            throw e;

        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
        }

    }
}
```

> Output:
>
> finally
>
> Arithmetic Exception
>
> In catch block if you code return instead of explicit throw of
>   exception then

```
public class StackOverFlowReturn {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                System.out.println(display());
            } catch (Exception ae) {
                System.out.println("Arithmetic Exception");
            }
        }

        static boolean display() {
            try {
                throw new ArithmeticException();
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                return true;

            } finally {
                System.out.println("finally");
            }

        }
    }
```

> Output:
>
> finally
>
> true

You: If in the catch block I do not include a throw statement, the compilation fails again with the previous reason.

> Answer: When you explicitly throw an exception in try block, then it
>   is not necessary to have an explicit throw in catch block. You can
>   code as follows:

```
 public class StackOverFlowReturn {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(display());
    }

    static boolean display() {
        try {
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Arithmetic Exception");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

> Output:
>
> Arithmetic Exception
>
> finally
>
> true